# Yii Framework CTabview Focus Issue

Tags: yii

I am trying to navigate tab3(BaseContact Edit Source) from tab2 (BaseContact EditStructure) button,

Please refer below screen shots...[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on "Start Import" an action should be called in a controller.
In this controller, you should have a "redirect". You can pass an url argument (#) in your "redirect" to switch to an other tab. 
Eg :

```
$this->redirect(array('offer/view', 'id' => $offer_id,'#'=>'tab2'));
```